# ¿Existe alguna funcion sleep para float en C?

Tags: c

Mi pregunta era si conocíais alguna función que haga lo mismo que `sleep` para 0.5 o 0.25 segundos. Es decir, si existiese algo así `sleep(0.25);` ya que la función `sleep` no funciona porque sólo vale para enteros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Vale* para enteros porque realiza pausas con resolución de **segundos**, así que ¿ para que utilizar otro tipo de argumento ?

Afortunadamente, tienes varias opciones, todas en el estandar *POSIX*:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int usleep(useconds_t usec);
```

que utiliza *microsegundos*, o bien

```
#include <time.h>

int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);

struct timespec {
  time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
  long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

Observa que utiliza *nanosegundos*: 1000000 nanosegundos = 1 milisegundo.

Advierte que, en ambos casos, la precisión difícilmente será exactamente la solicitada; siempre estarás a merced de la carga de trabajo del sistema, su reloj hardware, ... Es decir, la pausa siempre será algo *mayor* que la pedida.

**EDITO**

La función `usleep( )` **ha sido eliminada** de los últimos *POSIX*; se recomienda utilizar la segunda, `nanosleep( )`.

Answer (score 1):

`Sleep()` es una función que recibe valores enteros para definir el tiempo de espera en milisegundos. Por lo que si quieres es definir una fracción de segundo, solo debes calcular ese fragmento de tiempo:

```
Sleep( 1000 ); // 1 segundo(1.0)
Sleep( 500 ); // 1/2 segundo (0.5)
Sleep( 250 ); // 1/4 segundo (0.25)
```

por lo tanto, solo multiplica tu valor decimal por 1000:

```
Sleep( (0.25)*1000 ); // 250
```

Comment: La pregunta original era con la funcion "sleep" de POSIX no la que tiene Microsoft "Sleep"

Answer (score 0):

Podrías re-implementar Sleep para que trabajes en segundos y no en milisegundos y donde ahí si le puedas pasar números decimales

```
void  SleepEx(float seconds)
{
  DWORD miliSeconds=seconds*1000;
  Sleep(miliSeconds);
}

int main()
{
    SleepEx(0.5);
    cout<<"Programa terminado"<<endl;
}
```